# subset of`{1, ..., 2n-1}` contains two numbers `m` and `k` that m + k = 2n or m - k = 0

Tags: combinatorics

Let the set A be any subset of`{1, ..., 2n-1}` where `| A | = n + 2.`
Now we have to prove that the set `A` contains two numbers `m` and `k` that

```
m + k = 2n or m - k = 0
```

Comment: Much better! Now it makes sense.

Comment: if $m-k=0$ then $m=k$

Comment: I guess, $|A| = n+2$ is more than required - your claim is true even for $|A| = n$. And I don't understand what you mean by two elements of the set $A$ are equal ($m=k$)...

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Partition $\{1,\ldots,2n-1\}$ into the sets $\{1,2n-1\},\{2,2n-2\},\ldots,\{n-1,n+1\}$, and $\{n\}$. How many of these sets are there? How big is the set $A$? What happens if $A$ contains two members of the same set?

Comment: I dont understand why we should do a partition.

Comment: @user180834: Because that sets you up to use the pigeonhole principle. Can you answer the three questions that I asked?

Comment: genius......... thanks sir

Comment: @Learner: You’re welcome.